# UIPopoverController displays at wrong position

Tags: autolayout, uipopovercontroller

I want to show a `UIPopoverController` when clicking on a label. All elements are laid out with AutoLayout.

```
// In TorHeimPopoverViewController.swift
// self.view is TorHeimPopoverViewController's view

popover.presentPopoverFromRect(label.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Left, animated: true)
```

It's displayed in another `UIPopoverController` (TorHeimPopoverViewController) and there in a Container

MainAppView -> TorHeimPopoverViewController -> ContainerView

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the `inView` parameter is wrong for this purpose. The rect of `label.frame` is in relation to the `ContainerView`, in which it is.

For example, when `label.frame` is `x = 300, y = 100`, it will take these coordinates, but use `self.view`  as origin and not the container.

[image]